# Change language on SQL Server 2005 permanently

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking how to change the language from English to Spanish permanently, for all sessions.

I reached it with this statement:

```
SET LANGUAGE spanish
```

But when I start a new session the English language comes back.

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs in serverfault.com, not here.

Comment: StackOverflow is set up to be a repository of answers to questions. Answering your own questions is totally acceptable. What you should do is move the answer from the question into its own answer and mark it as the accepted answer so people know this question has been answered.

Comment: @Chris Latta: thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved! I have changed the **Default Language** from **English** to **Spanish** modifying the properties of my login user.